# Show that there exists an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $m(E\cap(a,b)) > \frac{1}{2}m(a,b) > 0$ when $m(E) > 0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, solution-verification, measurable-sets

Let $E \subset [0,1]$ be a non-zero measurable set. Show that there exists an open interval $(a,b)\subset [0,1]$ such that $m(E\cap(a,b)) > \frac{1}{2}m(a,b) > 0$.

Proof: I will do it by contradiction and I want a proof verification.

Assume that

$m(E) > 0, \mbox{ and } \forall (a,b) \mbox{ open interval } m(E\cap (a,b)) \leq \frac{1}{2}m(a,b) \leq 0$

Consider $(a,b) = (0,1)$, then

$$ m(E\cap(0,1)) = m(E) > 0$$

That would contradict that $m(E) \leq 0$

I think that there is a mistake in my negation of the inequality because every measure has to be positive. How can I approach this ?

Comment: In the contradiction, you should indeed say $m(E\cap (a,b)) \leq \frac{1}{2}m(a,b)$. But not $m(E\cap (a,b)) \leq \frac{1}{2}m(a,b) \leq 0$ as the measure is non negative.

Comment: Yeah, the proof is incorrect.  Remember that "$u<v<w$" is shorthand for "$u<v$ and $v<w$."  The negation is "$u\geq v$ or $v\geq w$."

Comment: Yeah, can I choose $E = (0,2/3)$ then it contradicts that the measure is less than $1/2$ because it's $2/3$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the above comments point out, your proof is not correct. Here's an approach to the problem. Note that for any given $\epsilon>0$, there exists a finite family of disjoint  intervals $I_j=(a_j,b_j)$ such that for $S=\cup_{j=1}^n I_j$, it holds
$$
m(E\triangle S)<\epsilon.
$$ This implies
$$
m(E\cap S)\ge m(E)-m(E\triangle S)>m(E)-\epsilon.
$$ On the other hand,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
m(E\cap S) = m\left(E\cap \left[\cup_{j=1}^n I_j\right]\right)&=&\sum_{j=1}^n m(E\cap I_j)\\&\le& \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^n m(I_j)=\frac{1}{2}m(S)\\&\le&\frac{1}{2}\left[m(E)+m(E\triangle S)\right].
\end{eqnarray}$$ Combining them, we have
$$
m(E)-\epsilon\le\frac{1}{2}m(E)+\frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$ Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we have
$$
m(E)\le \frac{1}{2}m(E)
$$ or $m(E)=0$. This contradicts $m(E)>0$.

Comment: Nice! I would like to see why $m(E\cap S)\ge m(E)-m(E\triangle S)>m(E)-\epsilon.$

Comment: It came from $E=(E\cap S )\cup( E\setminus S)\subset (E\cap S) \cup (E\triangle S)$ and the fact that $E\cap S$ and $E\triangle S$ are disjoint. This gives $$m(E)\le m(E\cap S)+m(E\triangle S).$$